# Devexpress ComboEdit Focus to options by text

Tags: wpf, combobox, devexpress

I am using ComboBoxEdit of DevExpress like this:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="0" EditValue="{Binding conti_cd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowSizeGrip="False"  x:Name="cboRegion"/>
```

Now, I donot allow user input text to this combox but,  I wanna select options in ComboBox by text.

[image]

Example:

I have a combobox like above.

When I type "**E**" the combobox will focus to "**EUROPE**" options.

I tried to research but I don't know how to do.

Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Just set `AutoComplete = true;`

Full code should be like this:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="0" EditValue="{Binding conti_cd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowSizeGrip="False"  x:Name="cboRegion" AutoComplete="true"/>
```

And if someone get the trouble like me, please read below comment:

> If the AutoComplete property is set to true, the text typed by an
>   end-user within the edit box is automatically completed, if it matches
>   a value displayed within the dropdown. By default, the AutoComplete
>   option is disabled for ComboBoxEdit, and enabled for LookUpEdit.
>
> The Auto-Complete feature is not supported if the combobox editor's
>   popup window is represented by a check box list.